# Special (French) characters in an ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, encoding, special-characters

I have an asp.net mvc view, in witch i'm setting the value of a textbox using jQuery, as shown in the code bellow.

```
$("#idTxWhat").val('@ViewBag.myValue');
```

The problem is, if the value of `ViewBag.myValue` contains a special character like (é or è), the text is not shown correctly.

exemple : *téléphone => t&#233 ;l&#233 ;phone*

I tried the solution proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130742/french-accent-not-shown-correctly-in-asp-net-mvc-view), but didn't work.

**EDIT :**

If I do the following :

```
<div id="myTestValue"></div>
...
$("#myTestValue").append('<span> my value : @ViewBag.myValue</span>');
```

The value appear correctly : *téléphone*

Thanks in avance.

Comment: Where does the data in ViewBag come from?

Comment: From my controller, and I debug it, it contains the correct value. I've add an edit to my question that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#idTxWhat").val($("<div>").html("@ViewBag.myValue").text());
```

Comment: `$("<div>").html("@ViewBag.myValue").text()` creates a temporary `<div>` tag, sets its html to the value in the ViewBag, and gets its text value. It's a way of decoding html.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **@Html.Raw**(yourString)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$("#idTxWhat").val(unescape('@ViewBag.myValue'));
```

SECOND TRY:

How about this then

```
var t = '@ViewBag.myValue';
t = decodeURIComponent(escape(t));
$("#idTxWhat").val(t);
```