# IIS Site has CurrentCulture en-GB but Currency is R. Where can I update this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cultureinfo

I am facing issues with currency formatting.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and my site is hosted on IIS 10 WS2019 in UK region.

The following string is giving me wrong output

```
@string.Format("{0:C}", paymentAmount)
@string.Format(CultureInfo("en-GB", "{0:C}", paymentAmount)
```

OUTPUT - "R2,500.00"

I am expecting "£2500.00"

I am not keen on placement of comma but it's currency symbol which is bothering me.

When I try

```
@string.Format(CultureInfo("en-US", "{0:C}", paymentAmount)
```

I get "$2500.00"

This above code works fine on other servers which are hosted in India.

What should I do?

**UPDATE**
I am able to fix this issue by simply adding "en-GB" as my current culture in web.config.

The above one is not fix, but workaround. Without above code, when I check currentCulture, it is en-GB and currentUICulture is en-US but currency symbol, it is "R". When I explicitly set it again to en-GB, problem disappears.

I have checked Registry and server regional settings, they have £.

The machine.config and web.config does not explicitly configure "R" as currency symbol.

Anywhere else I need to check?

Comment: Wonder what is the encoding of the view... Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130812/2265446)

Comment: "R" as currency symbol seems to be the South-African Rand - does that ring a bell?

Comment: @cleptus - its Windows CodePage 1252

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - It does, thanks.  long ago we had hosted a site for south african client on the same server.  However I have checked server regional settings and it has £ there. See my update section.